# How to animate card component whose data is fetched from backend to such that there is delay in each card animation in Framer Motion

Tags: animation, tailwind-css, transition, framer-motion

I am fetching the card data from backend and i want to animate the card such that there is a delay in each card's animation using framer motion.

```
{data.map((item, index)=>{
          return <motion.div key={index}
          initial={{x:100}}
          transition={{duration:1}}
          whileInView={{x:0}}
          viewport={{
            once:true
          }}
          >
          <Card className='glow bg-gray-50'>
            <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle className='mt-5'>
                  <p className="font-normal text-blue-500">0{index + 1}</p>
                    <p className="font-normal mt-5 mb-2 text-blue-500">{item.title}</p>
                </CardTitle>
                <CardDescription className='opacity-70'>{item.content}</CardDescription>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter>
                <Link href={`/card/${item.slug.current}`} className="text-blue-500">See more</Link>
            </CardFooter>
        </Card>
        </motion.div>  
        })}
```

This is the card component.
I am using shadcn Card component.

I don't have any idea how it we add delay in each cards transition.